# How to check if iptables is empty from a script

Tags: bash, iptables

I am writing a script that needs to check if iptables is empty.

The only idea I have is to do "iptables-save" and compare it with a "iptables-save" of an empty iptables.

However, I'm not sure whether I can count on it that "iptables-save" produces the same result on every host for empty iptables.

Any idea?

Comment: `iptables -L` and parse if necessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `iptables-save` and grep for lines starting with `-`:

Empty iptables:

```
sudo iptables-save | grep '^\-' | wc -l
0
```

Non empty:

```
sudo iptables-save | grep '^\-' | wc  -l 
13
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the `--list` (-L) argument?

```
$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

That output shows that there are no firewall entries.

If it did output you would see something like this...

```
$ sudo iptables -n -L -v --line-numbers
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state INVALID
2    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
3    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
4    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
2    DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state INVALID
3    TCPMSS     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp flags:0x06/0x02 TCPMSS clamp to PMTU
4    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
5    wanin      all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
6    wanout     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
7    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
Chain wanin (1 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
Chain wanout (1 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
```

EDIT:  Here is a one liner you can use:  `echo "$(sudo iptables -n -L -v --line-numbers)" | egrep "^[0-9]"`.  Then just test if $? is 1 or 0.  If its 0 then there are active firewall rules, if 1 then no active rules.

```
$ echo "$(sudo iptables -n -L -v --line-numbers)" | egrep "^[0-9]"
1        0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       202.54.1.2           0.0.0.0/0
$
$ echo $?
0
$
$ sudo iptables -D INPUT 1
$
$ echo "$(sudo iptables -n -L -v --line-numbers)" | egrep "^[0-9]"
$ echo $?
1
```

EDIT:  Or using wc -l might be better....

```
echo "$(sudo iptables -n -L -v --line-numbers)" | egrep "^[0-9]" | wc -l
```